# How to resolve Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: mysql

enter code hereI'm getting the following error when I try to run query.

Error:Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '( add last_name varchar(20) )' at line 2

Query:

ALTER TABLE Durgesh.student1
(
ADD last_name VARCHAR(20)
);

Answer (score 1):

If you're using MySQL, the right syntax is:

```
ALTER TABLE Durgesh.student1 ADD COLUMN last_name VARCHAR(20);
```

More info [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html)